# ./src/app/app.module.ts:3:0-58 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser'

Tags: angular

i get this error "./src/app/app.module.ts:3:0-58 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser' in 'C:\Users\Amine\mon-app-0\src\app'

./src/main.ts:1:0-65 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser' in 'C:\Users\Amine\mon-app-0\src'

Error: src/app/app.component.html:428:25 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngSwitch' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

428   <div class="terminal" [ngSwitch]="selection.value">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:2:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:10:12 - error NG1010: Value

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

> Failed to compile." whenever i use the command `ng serve` or `run start` in command prompet

i tried looking for a solution online but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Import BrowserModule in the AppComponent.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

[BrowserModule Documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule)

Comment: According to the error message, he is already trying to do that, but it throws errors.